# select OnChange not working within a form

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm still relatively new to all this so please bear with my hackjob code. I'm attempting to use JavaScript to toggle the visibility of a div on my webpage once the value of a dropdown menu is changed. For some odd reason, it is not working and I have exhausted every solution I have come up with. Google doesn't help too much, mainly cause I don't know the correct terms to search for and what to look for.

Could anyone help me with this? Here is the code I am having issues with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(options) {
        var e = document.getElementsById(options);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';

    }
</script>

 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Services">Please select a service</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="Services" onchange="toggle_visibility(options);">
                    <option>Please select...</option> 
                    <option value="1">Regular Clean</option>
                    <option value="2">One-off Clean</option>
                    <option value="3">Spring Clean</option>
                </select>
            </div>


        <div id="options" style="display: none;">
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Open console (hit f12) and look at your errors. Put a `console.log("options", options)` right before you try to get elements by id. You will see you already have the select dom element and that is throwing an error when you try to `document.getElementById`.  You should really look into "javascript debugging techniques", it will definitely make your development life a little bit easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `getElementsById`, which isn't valid JavaScript, it should be `getElementById`. Also, your parameter and argument names are the same, so here's what I'd do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility() {
        var e = document.getElementById("options");
            if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
            else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}

</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Services">Please select a service</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="Services" onchange="toggle_visibility();">
        <option>Please select...</option> 
        <option value="1">Regular Clean</option>
        <option value="2">One-off Clean</option>
        <option value="3">Spring Clean</option>
    </select>
</div>


    <div id="options" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Or keep the param and just skip the entire `document.getElementById` line as they are already passing the triggering element. The second dom select is unnecessary

Comment: thank you!!! this immediately fixed my problem. i've been tryring to fix this for the past hour and a half, only if i knew it was this simple ahahah. thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeking to alternate visibility per menu change, you have the correct pattern but are missing a few details:

1. `getElementsById` is not a function (it's `getElementById` singular--each id is unique).
2. `options` is an undefined variable, not a parameter like you think it is.
3. There is no content in the `<div>` element you're showing/hiding, so it's hard to verify that anything is working.
4. Your `<div>` has no closing tag.
5. Use `camelCase` instead of `snake_case` in JS (cosmetic but important).

```js
function toggleVisibility() {
  var e = document.getElementById("options");
  e.style.display = e.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Services">Please select a service</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="Services" onchange="toggleVisibility();">
    <option>Please select...</option>
    <option value="1">Regular Clean</option>
    <option value="2">One-off Clean</option>
    <option value="3">Spring Clean</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="options" style="display: none;">Hello world!</div>
```

You may also consider researching [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) and avoiding inline CSS in the interests of keeping your behavior, style and markup separate.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `options` is meaningless in your `onchange` attribute.  You can just pass that as a string to getElementById (Element, not Elements). If you are just showing/hiding the div any time the dropdown is changed, it's relatively straightforward:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility() {
        var e = document.getElementById("options");
        if (e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
   }
</script>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Services">Please select a service</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="Services" onchange="toggle_visibility();">
        <option>Please select...</option> 
        <option value="1">Regular Clean</option>
        <option value="2">One-off Clean</option>
        <option value="3">Spring Clean</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div id="options" style="display: none;">
```